# Is the AgoraRTMWrapper in XCode necessary?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, agora.io

I have been dealing with the same issue for a few days now. I'm unable to upload any app store connect files due to the libAgoraRTMWrapper file. To be clear, this entire app has been built through Unity using agora SDK. The reason for failure, according to XCode, is that the wrapper "doesn't have the correct file type for this location". Invalid Swift support.

This leads me to wonder if the libagoraRTMWrapper is even necessary. Yes, I would like to keep using RTM but not at the expense of several build failures.

As a sidenote, XCode does mention that the build is being made for iOS but the wrapper was built for iOS + iOS simulator. I don't remember ever specifying that but it could just be the way the SDK was initially imported.

Answer (score 0):

this library is necessary for RTM to work.  Do you have a custom build setting for the project? It is verified that the included SDK Demo works on iOS builds.  Perhaps you can build that and compare the build setting to yours to find out what went wrong?